# Can't talk to QnAMaker bot in Azure or Teams, but can locally with emulator

Tags: azure, bots, azure-qna-maker

I created a QnAMaker bot through the website https://www.qnamaker.ai, which then took me through the steps creating the bot in Azure.

When I click on the Test in Web Chat section of the bot in Azure, before I've even typed anything, an error message arrives in  Channels > Web Chat > Issues that states: "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized"

I have download the code of the bot locally, and running it with npm, using ngrok and the Bot Emulator, I have successfully managed to connect to the bot and it works.

I haven't touched the AppID or Password in the Bot's settings in Azure, and these are the same credentials I used for the local bot that works.

Could someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the bot entirely and creating a brand new one. I think the issue with some sort of mix up with the AppID and AppPassword, even though they were both correct in the settings